# Why does resizeable() need to be the first method in a View?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Using XCode11 beta 4 here:

Why does the `.resizable()` method need to be listed first to not crash the Canvas?

For example:

**Works**

```
struct CircleImage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("Pizza")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4)
            )
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }

}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
struct CircleImage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("Pizza")            
            .scaledToFit()
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4)
            )
        .shadow(radius: 10)
    }

}
```

The error seems misleading:

`Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'`

Comment: Just a guess, but modifiers aren't processed in "batch", but instead are processed in "order". (Obvious.) So first question is - does your "doesn't work" View "work" on a real device? Next up - the misleading error. It's actually *better* than what you would have received in beta 1! The build errors Xcode gives in `SwiftUI` are not only misleading, all they actually mean any more is "something somewhere isn't correct". (At least to me.) Remember, it's only beta 4. At least your error pointed to the correct modifier. :-)

Comment: @dfd Yes it is true. SwiftUI errors are so misleading, that we have become blind to them. In this case, it is pointing you to the right reason, but we are so used to ignore them, that it goes unnoticed! Check my answer for a full explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that many times compile errors in SwiftUI are very misleading. But in this case, it is not.

Look at the declaration of `resizable()` and `scaledToFit()`:

```swift
extension View {
    @inlinable public func scaledToFit() -> some View
}
```

```swift
extension Image {
    public func resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets(), resizingMode: Image.ResizingMode = .stretch) -> Image
}
```

`scaledToFit()` is an extension of View. That means you can use it to modify any view. While `resizable()` is an extension of Image, so you can only use it on an Image.

And because scaledToFit() returns `some View`, it is no longer technically an Image. That means you cannot call `.resizable()` on it.

Same thing happens with `.font()` and `.fontWeight()`. They can only be applied to `Text` and in turn they also return Text. Which means these combinations are valid:

```swift
Text("hello").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).frame(width: 300)
Text("hello").fontWeight(.bold).font(.title).frame(width: 300)
```

but these are not:

```swift
Text("hello").font(.title).frame(width: 300).fontWeight(.bold)
Text("hello").frame(width: 300).fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
Text("hello").fontWeight(.bold).frame(width: 300).font(.title)
```

Because `.frame()` returns `some View`, you can no longer use `Text` specific modifiers.

Now look at your error message again: `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'`. It is saying `some View` does not know `resizable`, and that is true, only `Image` does.

*Declarations have been cleaned up in beta4. When a view was modified, instead of returning `some View`, they used to return some very long types, such as: `Self.Modified<_FrameLayout>` or `Self.Modified<_AspectRatioLayout>`*

Comment: Good answer... although, I wonder why they didn’t choose a way of writing these functions that would return the type of view that was put into it using generics etc...

Comment: Oh... just saw your last paragraph... looks like they are doing that. 